# Why is there some weird sphere, and how come it's part of a texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]For some weird reasons, I was working on this 10-second animation, when all of a sudden, some weird ball came out of nowhere, and I can't move it, because then I'll move the entire floor. Can someone help? Here's some screenshots: Oh wait, the file's too large. Can't. Sorry, but I think you get the idea. I'm also a noob.

Comment: if, when you move the sphere the floor moves, it is most likely joined to the floor. Select the floor and then press Space to search and enter "separate" then click Separate and "By Loose Parts". The sphere will be a separate mesh and you should be able to find it in the Outliner.

Comment: Oof, turns out it wasn't stuck to anything. However, it just can't move at all. It won't move anywhere.

Comment: Make a copy of the .blend file and remove everything unrelated and the upload the file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and we can have a look.

Comment: Ok, doing that right now. Is it ok, because it says that the file is too large.

Comment: Wait I can't the file is too large, what do I do now?

Comment: "Remove everything unrelated" should get the file size down and you can remove the textures/images. How big is the file? I have seen some really large files uploaded there.

Comment: I believe 81 MiB